# What plant is this? Might be a tree, but still a sapling. No flowers yet

Tags: identification, trees

[image: plant photo]
Found this in my backyard, has been growing for 1-2 years.

Comment: Hi Sameer, can you tell us where the picture is taken? What part of the world?

Comment: this is from the west coast, the Bay Area of California to be specific - San Jose. I thought it might be fig but the fig tree I have doesn't have red branches and the leaves aren't shaped like this.